# C# Xamarin not displaying cyrillic

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm new to C# and coding so forgive me for my uneducated question.

I'm taking a course for C# on Xamarin. Yesterday everything was fine and today when I write a text in Cyrillic in Xamarin, what I get when I run it is "?????????".

I have tried changing from Console to Lucida, but it did nothing.

When I changed the Windows 10 language to Bulgarian, it is working properly. But I rather have my Windows back in English.

P.S. The problem is shown in the console when I run the code. It is looking fine in Xamarin.

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/388500/1558147

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not see this before I made my post, but that`s pretty much how I fixed it ... but it took a lot longer to find different solutions and test them. Thank you anyway!